How to transform the left image into the right image?
I want to transform the image on the left into the image on the right. How can I achieve this?
The possible transformation operations may include:

A. Perform blurring.
B. Get the hue image.
C. Perform histogram equalisation.
D. Perform pixel segmentation.
E. Perform sharpening.
F. Perform image inversion.

The image on the right may be obtained through a combination of these operations.

Original Pic:

Could you provide me with some ideas? Thank you very much!

I have tried each one of them and some combinations, but none of them produced a result similar to this, as shown in the image below.



that's a homework assignment or something, isn't it? what have you tried? have you tried any of these operations yet? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and [ask] and [mre]

What have you tried? If I were you, I would begin by trying each of the possible transformations on the original image and deciding which one looks promising. Then I would take that image and apply each of the other transformations to it, and so on.

I have tried all the transformations, but none of them look similar. I'm really out of ideas.

you haven't tried a stronger blur. can you tell why you need a stronger blur?

@Christoph Rackwitz ,The image now looks somewhat similar when I use a blur kernel of 305x305. However, the image on the right seems to have a cross-like shape in the middle. Is there any way to improve it further?

yes. what blur types do you know?

@Christoph Rackwitz gaussian blur, average blue and median blur, all right, I'll try each of them.

@Christoph Rackwitz Thank you so much! Average Blur is the answer in the image!

Take the hue channel and blur it. Done.

a class mate of yours just asked the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79150138/how-to-convert-and-blur-the-image-to-the-following-output

One way to do that in Python/OpenCV is to convert to HSV. Then get the Hue channel and blur it.


Thanks!If I increase the size of the blur kernel, the image looks somewhat similar.

average blur works!

OK. I used a Gaussian blur above.  Average blur may look closer to what you wanted. I did not try that.
